# Share Cognos report with non-users

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I would like to share a Cognos Analytics 11.1.6 (active) report with the entire organisation, thus including people without a license. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an Active Report is that it is portable.  Output from an Active Report can be viewed outside the Cognos environment.  You should be able to schedule the report to be sent via email to whoever needs it and they can interact with the data contained therein.

That being said, I don't use Active Reports because they rely on specific browsers that my organization does not allow.  So there may be other limitations (amount of data, for example) that I don't know about.

Comment: While active reports still have downsides in terms of portability, among other things, have you heard that IBM has now created an "[Active Report Viewer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.2.0?topic=reports-active-report-viewer)" since many folks no longer have access to Internet Explorer?  I'm not sure on the licensing so it may not help much but I found it somewhat interesting since I figured the reduction in IE deployments would simply encourage IBM to move away from the MHT technology.